# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Один из ярких примеров внедрения новых технологий — разработанная нами (,) совершенно новая конструкция для перевозки вязких нефтепродуктов,  шиберная задвижка диаметром 200 миллиметров.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, тут запятая не нужна. Мы имеем дело не с перечислением, а с описанием предметы (в данном случае конструкции) с разных сторон. Вот, если бы, скажем, было так: "...разработанная нами, усовершенствованная другой фирмой конструкция" - тогда да.
Думаю, специалисты лучше объяснят с точки зрения лингвистики.

Comment: Да, в таком случае было бы два однородных определения, выраженных причастиями с зависимыми словами, разделенных запятой.

Answer (score 2):

Это неоднородные определения, запятая не нужна. Неоднородны они по семантике, кроме того, можно использовать формальное позиционное правило (причастный оборот стоит ПЕРЕД определением:

1) Если определительный оборот стоит перед определением, то они чаще всего (хотя не всегда) считаются неоднородными: "Наверх вела устланная коврами широкая лестница".

2) Если определительный оборот стоит после определения, то они  являются однородными:  "Вокруг простираются белые, покрытые снегом равнины".

Answer (score 0):

Не нужна, поскольку здесь нет перечисления или уточнения. Причастный оборот "разработанная нами" поясняет физическое происхождение подлежащего "конструкция" вместе с определением "совершенно новая". Этот причастный оборот не требует собственной запятой (т.е. "разработанная нами конструкция"), в силу предшествования подлежащему. Но имеющуюся запятую, возможно, лучше заменить двоеточием, поскольку далее конкретизируется, "что за конструкция".

Answer (score 0):

В данном предложении причастным оборотом является вся конструкция: разработанная нами  совершенно новая конструкция для перевозки вязких нефтепродуктов. Разработанная нами - не составляет п/о.

Answer (score 0):

Коли цель сказать о конструкции - зпт. не нужна.
Если я выделяю "НАМИ", зпт. нужна. 
Предложение неграмотно.
Правильно. Один из примеров внедрения новых технологий — разработанная нами конструкция для перевозки вязких нефтепродуктов или Один из примеров внедрения новых технологий, нами разработанная, (-) конструкция для перевозки вязких нефтепродуктов.
 1. тире - факульт., зависит от силы желаемого фразового ударения.
 2. пример не умеет быть ярким (не лампочка или цвет) - это канцелярит; но может быть удачным, хорошим.
 3. конструкция: новая или неновая, совершенно новый - канцелярит. Маша родила сына - не нового сына и не совершенно нового сына. Автор выпустил новую книгу - не совершенно новую. Здесь *новая избыточно, потому что новая технология.
 Стилистич. ошибка и смысловая. Заслонка не умеет перевозить продукт, даже если он и нефте. Нужно: новая задвижка для перевозки жидкого продукта в цистерне.